# Suppose that $P[Z \le X]= P[Z \ge X]$ where $Z$ is standard normal. Does this mean that $X$ symmetric?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Give a random variable $X$ suppose
that $$P[Z \le X]= P[Z \ge X]$$ where $Z$ is standard normal independent of $X$.
The question is does this mean that $X$ is symmetric (i.e., $X \stackrel{d}{=} -X)$.

Comment: No. Say that $X \in \{-1, 2\}$ and $P(X=-1) = p$ and $P(X=2) = 1-p$. You can adjust $p$ in such a way your condition holds.

Comment: @nicola Thanks for the example.  Do you have any idea of what this say about $X$?